# Create new table with number of incidents per month

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

Whats up mates , i have already started to learn SQL database thing and i am confused here . i have to create a table with number of incidents per month.
I already know how to create table but the rest ?

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(month FROM dateofcall) AS x,
    incidentnumber,
    dateofcall
FROM
    incidents
GROUP BY
    incidentnumber,
    x
ORDER BY
    x ASC;
```

But its not giving me the results of incidents number per month . =(

Comment: You mentioned three different makes of DBMS server in your tags. Which one are you using? They're not all the same. Also, you may find it helpful to read some examples of GROUP BY usage.

Comment: I am sorry i am new here :) made some mistake
Im working on Dbeaver

Comment: Dbeaver is a database client tool that works with MySQL, Microsoft SQL server, PostgreSQL, IBM db2, oracle, and the like. But the details of the SQL language depend on the server you're using, not dbeaver.

Comment: I am absolutely new to this sorry , its working with PostgreSQL :)

Comment: I will edit the tags in your question. Don't be sorry. The point of this service is to help newcomers. Welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are grouping by too many items in your GROUP BY clause, and you are not COUNTing your incidents, just showing their details.

Try this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM dateofcall) AS x,
       COUNT(*) AS incidents    
FROM
   incidents
GROUP BY
    EXTRACT(month FROM dateofcall)
ORDER BY
    EXTRACT(month FROM dateofcall)
```

Comment: **Thanks mate ! exactly what i was looking for ! Cheers 
Will vote you up when i get more reputation :)**

Comment: You can  use `group by 1 order by 1` instead of `group by EXTRACT(month FROM dateofcall) order by EXTRACT(month FROM dateofcall)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(month FROM dateofcall) AS theMonth,
    COUNT(*) AS theNumberOfIncidents
FROM
    incidents
GROUP BY
    EXTRACT(month FROM dateofcall)
ORDER BY
    theMonth
```

Your original query wasn't counting anything. You were also grouping by `incidentNumber` which I assume is your primary-key, which is a nonsensical operation.

Due to a quirk in the SQL language you cannot use a column alias in `GROUP BY` statements, which is why you need to duplicate the `EXTRACT(month FROM dateofcall)` code.

Comment: **Man awesome ! i was just trying the same thing right now and you helped me with the group by :) ! Thanks a lot @Dai
I want to vote your answer up but i m new here it seems like i need more reputation**